# Too many mysql instances. How to kill?

Tags: mysql, instance, mysqld, process

I should be ashamed of myself, for asking, I know.

Check out this screenshot attached. [image]

My server, which is indeed not seeing HUGE amounts of traffic, should not be this overloaded. Mysql is having a party and everyones invited. The thing is I don't like these kinds of wild parties.

How do I kill this stuff? How do I regulated it so that it doesn't keep happening? Pretty soon my host is going to call the police and the party will be over for everyone.

Comment: I thought everyone likes parties ;)

Comment: Yeah, but this is one of those hard-rocking memory intensive parties that make page-load slow. Plus I wasn't invited - I only discovered it by happenstance which means no matter how good it is I don't like it.

Comment: In addition to what Rolando has said, it is impossible to start two instances on the same port with MySQL. I frequently mess around with my own compiled from source instances and forget to reset the port in my.cnf - any attempt to start the new server on an in-service port just fails. So, unless you've configured about ~ 30 my.cnf s with 30 different port numbers, it's not possible that you are really have that many instances running.

Comment: @1Up Do not worry, MySQL seems to be using only 20% of the available memory, and you seem to have 50% of *freeable* memory, so I do not see nothing to worry right now.

Answer (score 4):

Don't be fooled by what you see.

mysqld will not multiple instances on the same datadir and ibdata1. How do I know this?

On Sep 26, 2014 I answered [MySQL got signal 11 error and slave is down](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/77736/mysql-got-signal-11-error/77789#77789). In my answer, I mentioned how InnoDB Architecture only allows one mysqld process to open a Master Thread to ibdata1.

Therefore, if you do not see the following lines in your error log

```
6 [Note] InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files.
2014-09-26 12:51:53 14166 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11
2014-09-26 12:51:53 14166 [Note] InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files.
```

In light of these things, I assure you, you do not have multiple mysqld processes.

What, then, are you seeing? Those are actual DB Connections emanating from the mysqld instance. I have seen this freakish display come from source-compiled versions of mysqld. I have mentioned it in passing in my old post [innodb_buffer_pool_size not changed](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17075/innodb-buffer-pool-size-not-changed/17109#17109) and [Identical mysql processes (ServerFault)](https://serverfault.com/questions/374900/identical-mysql-processes/375002#375002). My suspicion is that the OS is manifesting DB Connections as if they were mysqld processes. On the contrary, they are just ordinary DB Connections.

You should run this in Linux

```
ps -ef | grep mysqld | grep -v grep | wc -l
```

You should get an output of 2 (1 for mysqld and 1 for mysqld_safe)

If you get just 1, you probably got a very old version of MySQL.

Comment: `pgrep mysqld` is your friend. 
@1Up It is also very easy to see if you change to "Tree mode" (F5): http://i.imgur.com/YeDtYP2.png MySQL will generate ~20 internal threads (not processes) even if there are no connections.